# Average/median hotel price per US county

Tags: data-request, usa, travel

I am looking for a dataset containing or allowing me to compute the average or median hotel price per US county. So far, I've only found the [average rent per US county](https://github.com/Franck-Dernoncourt/US-cost-of-living-per-county/blob/main/cost%20of%20living%20again.csv) ([visualization](https://redd.it/10ci5vc)), but not for hotels.

Comment: Any answers or comments are welcome.

Comment: I am still interested in this question.